# Linking a console application to a graphical application in python

Tags: python, import, console

I'm trying to make a game in python (using pygame) that uses a console menu as the initial program, which then opens a graphical window generated by pygame if the corresponding option is selected. I have a file called "bship.py" which contains a typical pygame application that opens an 800x600 window and I can't figure out how to open it when '1' is pressed... I've tried the "import" function but to no avail. Here's the code!

```
print 'MAIN MENU'
print '----------'
print '\n'
print '1. Play'
print '2. Exit'
print '3. Credits\n\n\n\n\n\n'
menuAnswer = raw_input("> ")
if menuAnswer == '1':
    #What is supposed to go here?
    #How can I run my pygame file? :P
    #"import bship" doesn't seem to work

elif menuAnswer == '2':
    exit()

elif menuAnswer == '3':
    import Credits

elif menuAnswer != ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
    print 'Invalid selection...'
    print 'learn to type, \n'
    print 'Press ENTER when you are ready'
    print 'to accept the repsonsibilities'
    print 'of being a player...'
    raw_input()
```

Comment: Think about how you run `bship.py` right now without using the above menu. Then read about the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. You can run `bship.py` as a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

```
if menuAnswer == '1':
     game = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "bship.py"])
     game.communicate()
```

Using Crayzeewulf's suggestion, I used the subprocess module to solve the problem! woop woop :D